# Rename files in subdirectory with the same name as the name of the folder

Tags: python

Here is my dilemma. I would like to use python to recursively walk through a directory and rename all the files the name of the folder. I know this has been asked a lot (for; appending, changing text/extension) in a using a variety of programming (third party software, bash, windows command line, perl), but I would really like to get this done in python, and I want the folder name to wholly replace the file name.

I understand the the "dirname" in the code below is the folder name, and ideally I could replace this:

```
dest =  root + '/' + dirname  + file
```

for this, assuming #extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]

```
dest =  root + '/' + dirname  + extension
```

I don't understand why this replace doesn't work. When I remove the "file" reference, I receive an error, telling me this file already exists. Ive also tried to slice (file[:10]), which works if you know exactly how many characters you need to replace (I want to limit hardcoding)

***Currently:***

C:\data\FolderA\foo.txt
C:\data\FolderB\foo.txt

***Code as written***

C:\data\FolderA\FolderAfoo.txt
C:\data\FolderB\FolderBfoo.txt

***What I need***

C:\data\FolderA\FolderA.txt
C:\data\FolderB\FolderB.txt

```
import os
import ntpath

path = "C:\data"

#recursively walk through the directory to find folders
for root, dir, files in os.walk(path):
  #walk through the folders to find files
  for file in files:
   dirname = ntpath.basename(root)
    #original location
    ori = root + '/' + file
    #From location, adding the dirname ("FolderA") before the file name
    dest =  root + '/' + dirname  + file
    os.rename(ori, dest)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't actually call `os.path.splitext(file)[1]`? Also you should use 4 spaces for your indents.

Comment: I hadn't included the "os.path.splitext(file)[1]" code as I knew that was the code I needed, but when I took out the var "file" in the second to last line, it would error out. I understand with the spacing, and will try to do a better job next time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)  

dest = root + '/' + dirname + ext
```

Comment: You could just use `ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]`.

Comment: This worked beautifully. I'm glad I was on the right track. I figured out that the issue was not with the code but the fact that files are not text (as I simplified for this example) but rasters that are each made up of several files;  the Test_DEM raster file would be made up of; Test_DEM.html, Test_DEM.img, Test_DEM.img.vat.dbf, and Test_DEM.img.xml. I need to figure out how to handle the multiple exentsions.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
import os

path = r"c:\data"

for path, sub_directories, files in os.walk(path):
    directory_name = os.path.split(path)[1]

    for file in files:
        extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
        source = os.path.join(path, file)
        destination = os.path.join(path, directory_name + extension)
        os.rename(source, destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple just do:

dest =  root + '/' + dirname  + "/" + dirname